# How can I find the file my storyboard outlet connects to?

Tags: swift, xcode

This may be a silly question.

I know I can easily go to my storyboard from my outlet e.g.

[image]

Is there an easy way to do the reverse?  I'd like to go from my storyboard element to my swift file, specifically the line of code where the outlet is declared.

[image]

Comment: This would make a good enhancement request. http://bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any shortcut link back to the declaration of an outlet. A couple of alternatives are:

1. Use the Assistant Editor (it's the middle button below with the two overlapping rings) while you have a View Controller or an element within it selected in a storyboard. It will load up the accompanying class in a panel beside the storyboard view.

   [image]
2. Select the View Controller itself out of the hierarchy, go to the Identity Inspector on the right, and tap the little gray circle icon with a white arrow in it beside the class name. That will take you to the class file in the main editor.

   [image]

Those are the only two methods I know of for getting to the associated class.

Comment: Thanks, this will certainly get the job done.  People in the future with this question: while you're in the assistant editor, look at the navigation bar up top and make sure you're in "Automatic" file selection mode (two overlapping circles) rather than "Manual" or you may find yourself looking at the wrong file.

Answer (score 1):

Select the element and then click "Show the Assistant editor" at the top right. It will take you to the correct class, but not to the exact line it is declared on.

Select element:

[image]

Click "Show the Assistant editor":

[image]